# Transgression homomorphism on cohomology

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I have one confusion about the transgression homomorphism which I found in two different books. I am unable to show that they really are same.

The first description of transgression homomorphism I found in a book "Cohomology of Number Fields" by Jurgen Neukirch (Proposition 1.6.5, Page 62), which is as follows:

**Proposition:** Let $K \triangleleft G$ and $A$ a $G$-module. There is a canonical homomorphism $tra: H^1(K,A)^{G/K} \rightarrow H^2(G/K,A^K)$, called transgression, which is given as follows:

If $h:K \rightarrow A$ is 1-cocycle in a class $\bar{h} \in H^1(K,A)^{G/K}$, then there exist a 1-cochain $f:G \rightarrow A$ such that $f|_K=h$ and that $\partial f(g_1,g_2)$ depends only on the cosets $g_1K$ and $g_2K$. For each such cochain $f$, $tra(\bar{h})=\bar{\partial f}$.

**Outline of Proof:** We construct a 1-cochain $f:g \rightarrow A$ with following properties:

(1) $f|_K=H$

(2) $f(gk)=f(g)+gf(k)$

(3) $f(kg)=f(k)+kf(g)$, $k \in K$ and $g \in G$.

For this, let $s:  G/K \rightarrow G$ be a section of the projection fro $G$ to $G/K$ such that $s(1)=1$. Since $\bar{h}$ is invariant under every $\gamma \in G/K$, we have $s(\gamma)h(s(\gamma)^{-1}ks(\gamma))-h(k)=kf(s(\gamma))-f(s(\gamma))$ for an element $f(s(\gamma)) \in A$.

For an arbitrary element $g=s(\gamma)k \in G$, we now set $f(g)=f(s(\gamma))+s(\gamma)h(k)$. Then one can check that $f$ satisfies conditions (1)-(3) above. One can also check that $\partial f(g_1,g_2)=g_1f(g_2)-f(g_1g_2)+f(g_1)$ depends only on the cosets.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Now, the second description of transgression homomorphism I found in "The Schur Multiplier" by G. Karpilovsky. Throut the book he considered $A$ to be trivial $G$-module. Hence in this case $H^1(K,A)=Hom(K,A)$ and $A^K=A$. The description of transgression is as follows:

Choose a section $\mu$ of projection from $G$ to $G/K$ and define $\phi :G/K \times G/K \rightarrow K$ by $\phi(x,y)=\mu(x) -\mu(x,y)+\mu(y)$. We therefore define a map from $Hom(K,A)$ to $H^2(G/K,A)$ by $\bar{\chi} \mapsto \bar{\chi \phi}$. This is called as transgression.

Comment: ...anyway, the reason this will turn out to be true is because in the first construction in the case $A$ is trivial you may take $f$ to be zero on elements of the form $s(\gamma)$.

Comment: @mt_ Thanks I have corrected errors

Comment: @mt_ One confusion is remained. If $f(\gamma)=0$, then $f(g)=h(k)$ for $g=\gamma k$. Since $h$ is homomorphism, $\partial f(g_1,g_2)=0$. This means that $tra=0$.

Comment: I don't see why that follows.  It is true if $G$ is a split extension of $G/K$ by $K$ (i.e. if you can find a subgroup $H$ such that $HK=G$), and indeed then we expect the transgression to be zero - see Evens, The Cohomology of Groups, section 7.3.  But suppose you have $s(a)s(b) = s(ab)k$ for some nonidentity $k$.  Then the transgression takes $[aK|bK]$ to $h(e) - h(k)+ h(e) = -h(k)$ which need not be zero.